# Extract rows from matrix by rownames (dates) in R?

Tags: r, date

Assume I have following Inputs:

```
Date <- seq.Date(as.Date("2000-01-01"),as.Date("2006-01-01"), by = "quarter") 

mat <- matrix(1:730,73,10) 
mat <- data.frame(mat)
mat$Time <- c(seq.Date(as.Date("2000-01-01"),as.Date("2002-12-01"), by= "month"),as.Date("2003-01-03") ,seq.Date(as.Date("2003-02-01"),as.Date("2004-12-01"),by ="month"),as.Date("2005-01-02"),seq(as.Date("2005-02-01"),as.Date("2006-01-01"), by ="month")) 
mat
```

And now I would like to get the rows in the matrix which are the same as the date vector. However, some of the dates in the Date vector dont exist. So iwould like to get the closest date. Therefore I tried this:

```
for(i in 1:length(Date)){
  if(Date[i] == mat$Time){
    Date[i] <- Date[i]
  }else{
    Date_Row <- which(abs(mat$Time - Date[i]) == min(abs(mat$Time -Date[i])))
    Date[i] <- mat[Date_Row,] 
  }
}

Date
```

But it doesn't work. How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: For testing purposes, can you post the `dput()` of your sample matrix?

Comment: You can simply convert the `rownames` into a column. I believe it  is less tedious than creating a new `Date` vector and then join them with the existing dates from your matrix.

Comment: I edited the question. I think you can understand the problem better now. My fault ...

Comment: This problem can be solved without loops, per my answer. In fact, one doesn't need to create a separate vector of quarterly dates, either.  The reference dates (i.e. start of each quarter) can be computed from the row names in the original data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can extract the row names and subset the data frame by assigning `year` and `quarter` values to the input data, then merging with the reference data that has one observation per quarter.

```
aFile <- " rowName      X1 X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X7  X8  X9 X10
2000-01-01  1 40  79 118 157 196 235 274 313 352
2000-02-01  2 41  80 119 158 197 236 275 314 353
2000-03-01  3 42  81 120 159 198 237 276 315 354
2000-04-01  4 43  82 121 160 199 238 277 316 355
2000-05-01  5 44  83 122 161 200 239 278 317 356
2000-06-01  6 45  84 123 162 201 240 279 318 357
2000-07-01  7 46  85 124 163 202 241 280 319 358
2000-08-01  8 47  86 125 164 203 242 281 320 359
2000-09-01  9 48  87 126 165 204 243 282 321 360
2000-10-01 10 49  88 127 166 205 244 283 322 361
2000-11-01 11 50  89 128 167 206 245 284 323 362
2000-12-01 12 51  90 129 168 207 246 285 324 363
2001-01-01 13 52  91 130 169 208 247 286 325 364
2002-11-01 35 74 113 152 191 230 269 308 347 386
2002-12-01 36 75 114 153 192 231 270 309 348 387
2003-01-03 37 76 115 154 193 232 271 310 349 388"

df <- read.table(text = aFile,header = TRUE, row.names = "rowName")
referenceDate <- seq.Date(as.Date("2000-01-01"),as.Date("2006-01-01"), 
                       by = "quarter")

library(lubridate)
quarterData <- data.frame(referenceDate,year = year(referenceDate),
                          qtr = quarter(referenceDate) )
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(date = ymd(rownames(df)),
              year = year(date),
              qtr = quarter(date)) %>% 
     left_join(.,quarterData)
```

...and the output:

```
   X1 X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X7  X8  X9 X10       date year qtr referenceDate
1   1 40  79 118 157 196 235 274 313 352 2000-01-01 2000   1    2000-01-01
2   2 41  80 119 158 197 236 275 314 353 2000-02-01 2000   1    2000-01-01
3   3 42  81 120 159 198 237 276 315 354 2000-03-01 2000   1    2000-01-01
4   4 43  82 121 160 199 238 277 316 355 2000-04-01 2000   2    2000-04-01
5   5 44  83 122 161 200 239 278 317 356 2000-05-01 2000   2    2000-04-01
6   6 45  84 123 162 201 240 279 318 357 2000-06-01 2000   2    2000-04-01
7   7 46  85 124 163 202 241 280 319 358 2000-07-01 2000   3    2000-07-01
8   8 47  86 125 164 203 242 281 320 359 2000-08-01 2000   3    2000-07-01
9   9 48  87 126 165 204 243 282 321 360 2000-09-01 2000   3    2000-07-01
10 10 49  88 127 166 205 244 283 322 361 2000-10-01 2000   4    2000-10-01
11 11 50  89 128 167 206 245 284 323 362 2000-11-01 2000   4    2000-10-01
12 12 51  90 129 168 207 246 285 324 363 2000-12-01 2000   4    2000-10-01
13 13 52  91 130 169 208 247 286 325 364 2001-01-01 2001   1    2001-01-01
14 35 74 113 152 191 230 269 308 347 386 2002-11-01 2002   4    2002-10-01
15 36 75 114 153 192 231 270 309 348 387 2002-12-01 2002   4    2002-10-01
16 37 76 115 154 193 232 271 310 349 388 2003-01-03 2003   1    2003-01-01
>
```

### Filter to dates near start of quarter

The reference dates in the OP are at the start of each quarter. Solutions for subsetting the joined data rely on this assumption.

Now that we've joined the data, if we want to subset to only the items early in the quarter, we can `filter()` based on the difference between `date` and `referenceDate` to keep those rows that are within the first 5 days of the quarter.

```
df %>% mutate(date = ymd(rownames(df)),
              year = year(date),
              qtr = quarter(date)) %>% 
     left_join(.,quarterData) %>% 
     filter(.,(date - referenceDate) < 5)
```

...and the output:

```
  X1 X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X7  X8  X9 X10       date year qtr referenceDate
1  1 40  79 118 157 196 235 274 313 352 2000-01-01 2000   1    2000-01-01
2  4 43  82 121 160 199 238 277 316 355 2000-04-01 2000   2    2000-04-01
3  7 46  85 124 163 202 241 280 319 358 2000-07-01 2000   3    2000-07-01
4 10 49  88 127 166 205 244 283 322 361 2000-10-01 2000   4    2000-10-01
5 13 52  91 130 169 208 247 286 325 364 2001-01-01 2001   1    2001-01-01
6 37 76 115 154 193 232 271 310 349 388 2003-01-03 2003   1    2003-01-01
>
```

### Filtering to a date beyond the first few days of quarter

If the first day in a quarter falls outside the criteria above, or if the input data includes multiple days that meet the filter criteria, another approach is to create a unique sequential number representing sorted dates within a year and quarter, and selecting the first item in the sequence.

```
# filter first obs in quarter
df %>% mutate(date = ymd(rownames(df)),
              year = year(date),
              qtr = quarter(date)) %>% 
     left_join(.,quarterData) %>% 
     arrange(.,year,qtr,date) %>% 
     group_by(year,qtr) %>%
     mutate(quarterSequence = seq_along(qtr)) %>%
     filter(quarterSequence == 1)
```

...and the output:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 15
# Groups:   year, qtr [7]
     X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6    X7    X8    X9   X10 date        year
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <date>     <dbl>
1     1    40    79   118   157   196   235   274   313   352 2000-01-01  2000
2     4    43    82   121   160   199   238   277   316   355 2000-04-01  2000
3     7    46    85   124   163   202   241   280   319   358 2000-07-01  2000
4    10    49    88   127   166   205   244   283   322   361 2000-10-01  2000
5    13    52    91   130   169   208   247   286   325   364 2001-01-01  2001
6    35    74   113   152   191   230   269   308   347   386 2002-11-01  2002
7    37    76   115   154   193   232   271   310   349   388 2003-01-03  2003
# … with 3 more variables: qtr <int>, referenceDate <date>, quarterSequence <int>
>
```

## A simpler approach: use the original data to create reference dates

We can solve the problem posed in the original post without joining one set of dates to another. How? We use `lubridate` functions to create the first day of the quarter for each row by parsing the `year` and `quarter` values from the dates provided in the row names of the original data frame.

```
# read same data file as top of this answer 
df <- read.table(text = aFile,header = TRUE, row.names = "rowName")
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
        mutate(date = ymd(rownames(.)),
               referenceDate = ymd(sprintf("%4d-%02d-%02d",year(date),
                                           (quarter(date)-1)*3+1,1))) %>% 
        filter(.,(date - referenceDate) < 5)
```

...and the output:

```
  X1 X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X7  X8  X9 X10       date referenceDate
1  1 40  79 118 157 196 235 274 313 352 2000-01-01    2000-01-01
2  4 43  82 121 160 199 238 277 316 355 2000-04-01    2000-04-01
3  7 46  85 124 163 202 241 280 319 358 2000-07-01    2000-07-01
4 10 49  88 127 166 205 244 283 322 361 2000-10-01    2000-10-01
5 13 52  91 130 169 208 247 286 325 364 2001-01-01    2001-01-01
6 37 76 115 154 193 232 271 310 349 388 2003-01-03    2003-01-01
```

Comment: liked how you filtered by the difference of the reference dates, smart. and using the read.table() function to read in the data is something I will keep a note of for more stackoverflow questions. Thank you

Comment: @DanielJachetta - you're welcome. After thinking about the problem a bit more, I realized one can create the reference dates from the original row names, no need for `join()`, per my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I copy and pasted  the top few rows of your data into an excel spreadsheet, then exported it to a csv to read into R as the variable `Book1`

I used your same code but changed the variable for clarity

```
Datetofind <- seq.Date(as.Date("2000-01-01"),as.Date("2006-01-01"), by = "quarter")
```

I got the dataset into a tibble to use `lubridate` and `tidyverse` the code below got the column into a Date format

```
Book1$Date <- ymd(Book1$Date)
```

Now I just used dplyr to filter the dates in your original datasets and return only the rows that match the quarters.

```
Book1 %>% 
filter(Date %in% Datetofind)
```

That got me the data below

```
 Date          X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6    X7   X8    X9   X10
  <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 2000-01-01     1    40    79   118   157   196   235   274   313   352
 2000-04-01     4    43    82   121   160   199   238   277   316   355
 2000-07-01     7    46    85   124   163   202   241   280   319   358
 2000-10-01    10    49    88   127   166   205   244   283   322   361
 2001-01-01    13    52    91   130   169   208   247   286   325   364
```

Comment: This don't solve the problem. As I mentioned there are some dates, which are in the vector, for instance 2003-01-01, but aren't in the matrix. So I need a for loop or a function for the nearest date, which is 2003-01-03 in this case. So how can I adjust the filter function to get those dates?